# @ngrx/effects gives TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5, ngrx

I have a scenario where I need to sequence two @Ngrx actions in my Angular application.

The first action updates the state with some data, and the second action uses that data to trigger a server call. I am using an Effect to sequence the two actions and trigger the second action only after the first one has completed.

To ensure the second action includes the recently updated data from the state, I inject the store into my effect and use a selector function to retrieve the data and include it as the payload for the second action.

This works.

**My Question**

However, I believe that since the `this.actions$` is already an observable stream, I should be able to simply transform each event on that stream and convert that into a different action.

A rough marble diagram of what I have in mind:
[image: rough idea]

I am using the `withLatestFrom` operator to combine the action stream with the data from the state.

```
  @Effect()
  lazyEffect1$ = this.actions$.ofType(LazyActions.TEST_ACTION_SEQUENCE)
     .withLatestFrom(this.filterId$, (x, y) => {
       return new LazyActionDone(y.number);
     });
```

But this code gives me an error:

**`TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`**

I have been able to get this to work using a slightly different construct, which is also included in the code below.

But I would like to understand why the `lazyEffect1` is not working. Where is my understanding failing me?

**The Code**

The NgRx Reducer:

```
// reducers.ts
export function lazyReducer(
  state: any = {},
  action: LazyAction | LazyActionDone
) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case LazyActions.TEST_ACTION_SEQUENCE: {
      console.info('Action Received in Reducer: ', action.type);
      return {
        ...state,
        number: action.payload
      };
    }

    case LazyActions.TEST_ACTION_SEQUENCE_DONE: {
      console.info('Done Received in Reducer: ', action.type);
      return {
        ...state,
        retrieved: action.payload,
        done: true
      };
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

The NgRx Effects:

```
// effects.ts
@Injectable()
export class LazyEffects {
  private filterId$: Observable<any>;

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private store: Store<any>
  ) {
    this.filterId$ = this.store.select(getLazyState);
  }

  // THIS DOES NOT WORK
  @Effect()
  lazyEffect1$ = this.actions$.ofType(LazyActions.TEST_ACTION_SEQUENCE)
     .withLatestFrom(this.filterId$, (x, y) => {
       // console.info(x, y);
       return new LazyActionDone(y.number);
     });

  // THIS WORKS
  @Effect()
  lazyEffect2$ = this.actions$.ofType(LazyActions.TEST_ACTION_SEQUENCE)
    .switchMap((action) => {
      console.info('Action Received in Effects: ', action.type);
      return of(action).withLatestFrom(this.filterId$, (x, y) => new LazyActionDone(y.number));
    });
}
```

Comment: Why don't you subscribe to the data change your first action is doing and then trigger the second action in that subscription?

Comment: I could. As I already mentioned, I have got it working using slightly different code.  But my question is not "How do I get this working?", but rather "Why isn't the original code working? What am I missing about the way @ngrx and observables work?"

Comment: I suspect the problem is with the effect initialisation and with `this.filterId$` in particular. The properties decorated with `@Effect` will be moved into the constructor and I'm guessing that `this.filterId$` is assigned *after* they themselves are assigned. From an RxJS perspective, the two effects you've declared are pretty much the same. For this reason, I favour declaring effects as functions, rather than properties.

Comment: @cartant Yes, if the `@Effect` decorator was internally moving the property into the constructor before the `this.filterId$` assignment, that would explain the behavior. Thanks! I hadn't considered that as a possibility.

Just curious though, can you share an example of declaring an effect as a function?

Comment: Instead of declaring an `Observable<Action>` property, declare a function that returns `Observable<Action>` and decorate it with `@Effect`. NgRx will see that it's a function and will call it to get the observable: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/v6.0.0-beta.3/modules/effects/src/effects_resolver.ts#L17-L19

Answer (score 0):

Just to spell out the solution [@cartant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6680611/cartant) [provided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938426/ngrx-effects-gives-typeerror-you-provided-undefined-where-a-stream-was-expec#comment92165608_48938426)..I believe the solution is to replace this property:

```
  // THIS DOES NOT WORK
  @Effect()
  lazyEffect1$ = this.actions$.ofType(LazyActions.TEST_ACTION_SEQUENCE)
     .withLatestFrom(this.filterId$, (x, y) => {
       // console.info(x, y);
       return new LazyActionDone(y.number);
     });
```

With this function:

```
  @Effect()
  lazyEffect1$() { 
     return this.actions$.ofType(LazyActions.TEST_ACTION_SEQUENCE)
     .withLatestFrom(this.filterId$, (x, y) => {
       // console.info(x, y);
       return new LazyActionDone(y.number);
     });
   }
```

[@cartant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6680611/cartant) deserves the credit for his answer in the comments, but I want to provide an answer/example for anyone else who comes across this issue and doesn't notice that the answer is in the comments.